# SetWindowPos doesn't work with put_Visible(false)

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, visual-c++, z-index

I am trying to use `SetWindowPos` to put a new opened IE window in the background.

The problem is that it only works after I use `put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE)`. While the window is not visible, `SetWindowPos` won't do anything. If I use `put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE)` before `SetWindowPos` this makes the window to appear on top for a second, and then go to the back.

How can I avoid this and make the new window appear in the background without appearing first on top?

Here is what I tried:

```
HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE
```

using `put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE)` before `SetWindowPos`, and then it works, but it shows on top of all windows before going to the back.

Comment: How are you calling SetWindowPos? Which flags, in particular.

Comment: HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE, I tested it using put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE) before SetWindowPos, and then it works, but as I said it shows on top of all windows before going to the back.

Comment: Try adding SWP_SHOWWINDOW . Failing that, it might be worth including some of the code so people can see more of what you're doing. It's a while since I've used IE like this so I'm not sure where you're getting its window handle from, etc., but if I saw the code something might jump out as a possible issue.

Comment: And/or maybe SWP_NOACTIVATE , if you find that SWP_SHOWWINDOW makes it take the input focus or come to the front.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want IE to appear at the bottom of the zorder?